# 'Upsizing Wizard cannot be run with any database objects open'

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I get that error when I try to link my table to a SQL server, I also get an error if I try to click the button when no table is open.

I just want to create a form for simple data entry into a SQL table. Haven't been able to find any simple gudies for this task, so any guides you can give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example copied directly from Access' Help topic for the TransferDatabase method.  It assumes a DSN (data source name) called "DataSource1" is available and points to desired external database.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
    "ODBC;DSN=DataSource1;UID=User2;PWD=www;LANGUAGE=us_english;" _
    & "DATABASE=pubs", acTable, "Authors", "dboAuthors"
```

Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure what you're attempting to do.  If your goal is to export an existing Access table to an ODBC database, you would use acExport as the transfer type with the TransferDatabase method.

Actually, if this is a one-time operation where you want to import/export/link between Access and an ODBC database, seems like it would be easier and faster to use the import/export options from the ribbon.  No programming required.

Comment: Hi Hans! To explain what I want to do, I have a SQL Server 2008 DB in operation with tables I have set up, and I want to create nice forms for my end-users to easily enter new employees into the table. I recall being able to create fancy forms for exactly this task in Microsoft Access, but trying it now, I don't know how to use it for a non-Access database. I will try your example, thanks.

Comment: OK, this should be easy.  Create a DSN for your SQL Server database if you don't have one already.  Then in Access 2007, select "External Data" from the choices listed along the top of the ribbon.  And then above "Import", open the dropdrown list labelled as "More", and choose "ODBC Database" from that dropdown.  You should then be at a wizardly dialog ("Get External Data ..."), and choose the radio button for Link (instead of the one for Import).  From there, I think the rest may be clear.  The hard part of this operation IMO is knowing where to get started.

Comment: Oops.  You figured it out before I completed the instructions.  :-)  Well done!  I'll leave the other comment in case it's helpful to someone else.